# Loading external files into oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created the below table.

```
create table emps( id varchar2(20), clobi clob);
```

Am trying to insert bfile into the COLBI column using the below procedure:

```
create or replace procedure bfii is 
   bfil bfile; 
   clo clob; 
begin 
   insert into emps values('3',empty_clob() ) returning clobi into clo;
   bfil := bfilename('clobr', 'Man.ext'); 
   dbms_lob.fileopen(bfil); 
   dbms_lob.loadfromfile(clo,bfil, dbms_lob.getlength(bfil)); 
   dbms_lob.fileclose(bfil); 
end;
```

But I'm getting the error message at run-time rather than compilation.

```
Error at line 2
ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 805
ORA-06512: at "SYS.HIMA", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Also looks like you're creating your own objects in the SYS schema, which isn't relevant, but is a bad idea.

Comment: Is 'clobr' the name of a directory on disk on where the file 'Man.ext' is stored?

Comment: So what was the problem - you hadn't created the directory, you were passing the wrong name, or something else? What kind of data is in the file - is it plain text, and if so is it in the same character set as the database?

Answer (score 1):

Directory names, like other objects, are created as uppercase by default unless the name was quoted. When you refer to the directory as a string it needs to match the case in the data dictionary (e.g. `all_directories`). So you need to change to:

```
   bfil := bfilename('CLOBR', 'Man.ext');
```

... even if you created it with `create directory clobr ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to [create directory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm) where your `Man.ext` file is stored

Comment: Many thanks all. Its working now. But its not displaying the exact characters what it is in my file as it is showing two small boxes instead of 2 words.