# ORA-29280 with utl_file.fremove()

Tags: oracle

I created with the full access to the folder but it's showing an error. I don't know where the mistake is. How can I fix this?

```
create or replace directory Utl_fileoption as 'd:\jk1';

DECLARE 
  filepath VARCHAR2(32767);
  F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
  Location1 Varchar(500);
BEGIN
  Location1:='Utl_fileoption';
  filepath:='jk.xls';
  UTL_FILE.FREMOVE(Location1,filepath);
END;
```

Error report:

```
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 251
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 1230
ORA-06512: at line 9
29280. 00000 - "invalid directory path"

*Cause: A corresponding directory object does not exist.
*Action: Correct the directory object parameter, or create a corresponding
directory object with the CREATE DIRECTORY command.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading external files into oracle database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160990/loading-external-files-into-oracle-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory names, like other objects, are created as uppercase by default unless the name was quoted. When you refer to the directory as a string it needs to match the case in the data dictionary (e.g. `all_directories`). So you need to change to:

```
Location1:='UTL_FILEOPTION';
```

... even though you created it with `create directory Utl_fileoption ...`

Comment: I have a variable as you "Location1:='UTL_FILEOPTION';" but always I get the same error ORA-06512

Comment: @delive - `UTL_FILEOPTION` is the specific directory name the original questioner was using (see the `create directory` statement in the question). You need to use the actual name of your own directory, which you can see in `all_directories`. (Assuming you've created a directory object, and you have permission to read/write, and it points to an Oracle-read/writable operating system directory on the DB server. ORA-06512 ins't that helpful, check the other errors you get, like the ORA-29280 in the question).